# Is it possible to show map marker without input the Lat/Long with Leaflet

Tags: laravel, leaflet, gis

as the title stated, I'm trying to develop a GIS (geographic information system) webpage, whereby the user (admin) can input location and picture, and the marker will be shown/popup in the main page's map. I'm using Laravel framework and Leaflet for the map to implement the GIS. I manage to show the map without any marker yet. As the admin want to add the location to show the marker in the main page's map, normally what i've seen is that you need to include the Lat/Long for that specific location. It is true that including Lat/Long can make the marker more accurate to pin point the exact location, and I think it is necessary thing to include, as it is the main source of information to the system for pin point the location. But as a user, sometimes they not as diligent as we thought, the problem will occur if they left the lat/long to 0, because they are too lazy to search for the lat/long, thus making the initial goal which is to show marker in the main map fail.

Is there a way to make the Lat/Long automatically filled as the user type their location information? Or is there any other technologies for the GIS that I could implement/use?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe this - [Leaflet.Autocomplete](https://github.com/tomik23/Leaflet.Autocomplete) ?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, then you are asking about this like
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/overview